# How can I load a Project Gutenberg book on my phone's Kindle app?

Tags: ebooks, kindle-for-android

The Gutenberg site's [guide to Mobile devices](https://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg:MobileReader_Devices_How-To) doesn't address this question. It recommends the FBReader which I may install if else fails, but I'd prefer to use the Kindle app.

Assuming it is possible, can somebody enumerate the steps to loading a book from the Project Gutenberg site to the Kindle App on my phone?

My phone is a Nexus 4 running Android 4.2.2.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out one fairly unsatisfactory way to do it:

1. Using phone browser (Chrome), go to [Gutenberg mobile site](http://m.gutenberg.org).
2. Find book ([for example](http://m.gutenberg.org/ebooks/174.mobile)) and download Kindle version.
3. Go to Downloads (under Apps) where you should find the mobi file listed (e.g. `pg174.mobi`).
4. Long touch the file until menu bar appears at top with Share icon.
5. Click Share Icon which will present pop-up menu which should include **Send to Kindle** option.
6. Choose **Send to Kindle** option, which will list the wrong title and author for the book. Edit title and author, checkmark the devices you wish to send it to as well as **Archive in your Kindle Library**, and press send.

The book didn't show up on my device immediately, but within 5 minutes it appeared in the app's home view.

I'm not sure what if any combination of events was required to get it downloaded to my device. I received an email from Amazon informing me that my document had been prepared and providing a link. I clicked that link from my phone. I also visited the store within the Kindle app. I'm not sure whether either of these acts was necessary or sufficient for finally accessing the book from my app.

Comment: I just followed the steps 1-6 and it worked, without needing to open email/click link/visit Store. I believe Amazon just needs to synchronize the data, hence the delay. Meanwhile, trying to do manual sync may help (choose "Sync" from the menu), but it still won't be instantaneous (I think I need 1-2 minutes before syncing it)

Answer (score 0):

I too tried the method above.
My phone is a Motorola moto 4 plus.
It refused to send to Kindle,
saying there is a problem with the document.
I tried both files with and without images.
In the end I downloaded the EPUB version
which Google books displayed perfectly,
even with images.
Heinz

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded a Gutenberg.org book (kindle file type) to my phone and emailed to my kindle email address. It put the book on my Kindle app on my Android phone. I added it on my Kindle dedicated ebook reader by going to the cloud and touching the image of the book cover to download..  I'm finding that the page I read to syncs across all my kindle devices.